# Conditional Formatting Highlighting blank Cells

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am using conditional formatting to highlight some cells which do not lie between the input range.While this I am getting blank cells highlighted as well.
Formula I used is

```
OR(B2<$R2,B2>$S2)
```

Here value of B2 is say -1
Value of R2 is -1 and S2 is also -1
The Row 1 just contains -1 in one cell(B2)
Except for that cell every other cell gets highlighted.
I am not getting the reason for blank cells getting highlighted

```
For illustration
    A  B  C .............P Q R  S
 1    -1                    -1 -1
 2
 3
 .
 .
```

So basically highlight the cells which have value outside the range(-1,-1) 
But this highlights all blank cells of the row 1 which ideally shoudnt because they dont have any value in them

Comment: `=AND(OR(B2<$R2,B2>$S2), B2<>"")` will exclude blank cells.

Comment: I figured out a way for it by using different formula the way you said.But I wanted the reason for such weird behavior of Excel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In formulae, Excel considers blanks as `0`, hence greater than -1.